# Tool for showing javascript, CSS, HTML dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am relatively new to JavaScript and trying to find a way to get a good overall understanding of JavaScript projects, frameworks, etc.. For example when I look at a JavaScript based source on Github I would like a **one page snapshot of the dependencies between the html, css and the various .js files** requiring further js files( modules) , instead of looking at the source code tree and opening up the individual files. What I am looking for is either an object diagramming tool or something like a "file diagram".

**Is there a tool out in the wild already doing this?** (and ,yes I have already tried Google-ing it)

(I used to use a [tool](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) in the Windows world for tracking DLLs which is a similar concept.)

Comment: I found Colony which is the closest to what I have been looking for. https://github.com/hughsk/colony

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/nodejitsu/require-analyzer gets you part of the way there.

One could also implement a file dependency analyzer if you are looking for more comprehensive html/template analysis with these two:

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/fs.html#fs.readdir

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/fs.html#fs.watchFile

Answer (score 0):

Using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) you can see the files requested by each page, the server response and you can filter them by type. The HTML view lets you see the entire page including related js/css content. I don't think it's exactly what you are looking for, but I find it helpful for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

here are some bookmarklet code that could help (taken from https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/webdevel.html

view style sheet :
javascript:s=document.getElementsByTagName('STYLE');%20ex=document.getElementsByTagName('LINK');%20d=window.open().document;%20/*set%20base%20href*/d.open();d.close();%20b=d.body;%20function%20trim(s){return%20s.replace(/^\s*\n/,%20'').replace(/\s*$/,%20'');%20};%20function%20iff(a,b,c){return%20b?a+b+c:'';}function%20add(h){b.appendChild(h);}%20function%20makeTag(t){return%20d.createElement(t);}%20function%20makeText(tag,text){t=makeTag(tag);t.appendChild(d.createTextNode(text));%20return%20t;}%20add(makeText('style',%20'iframe{width:100%;height:18em;border:1px%20solid;'));%20add(makeText('h3',%20d.title='Style%20sheets%20in%20'%20+%20location.href));%20for(i=0;%20i

view scripts:
javascript:s=document.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT');%20d=window.open().document;%20/*140681*/d.open();d.close();%20b=d.body;%20function%20trim(s){return%20s.replace(/^\s*\n/,%20'').replace(/\s*$/,%20'');%20};%20function%20add(h){b.appendChild(h);}%20function%20makeTag(t){return%20d.createElement(t);}%20function%20makeText(tag,text){t=makeTag(tag);t.appendChild(d.createTextNode(text));%20return%20t;}%20add(makeText('style',%20'iframe{width:100%;height:18em;border:1px%20solid;'));%20add(makeText('h3',%20d.title='Scripts%20in%20'%20+%20location.href));%20for(i=0;%20i